# change jqGrid options in Struts 2

Tags: eclipse, jqgrid, struts2

Where can i change this options:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options
in jqGrid Struts 2 plugin + Eclipse.

I need this to change the ignoreCase option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not supported in tags then you can try to change it in javascript. Get jqGrid object from DOM and apply options to it.

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#id_of_element").jqGrid({
    // options here 
  });
});
```

Comment: i am not so good with java script. How can i access this objects ?

Comment: Updated my answer with example.